Proximal operator of the Moreau envelope
I'd like to know if there is known general formula for computing the proximal operator of the Moreau envelope of a given suitable function.
Given the following definition of Moreau envelope
$$
M_{\rho,g}(x)=\min_{x'}\dfrac{1}{2\rho}||x'-x||^2+g(x'),
$$
and proximal operator
$$
\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda,g}(x)=\arg\min_{x'}\dfrac{1}{2}||x'-x||^2+\lambda g(x'),
$$
my question is about whether a general formula exists for the following expression
$$
\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda,M_{\rho,g}}(x)=??
$$
Some naive calculations suggest that $\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda,M_{\rho,g}}(x)=\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda+\rho,g}(x)$, but this can't be true (e.g. consider $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}||x||^2$).

Google "proximal operator of inf-convolution of functions".

After a good night sleep, found an answer:
$$
\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda M_{\rho,g}}(x)=\dfrac{\lambda\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda+\rho,g}(x)+\rho x}{\lambda+\rho}.
$$
